# jquery checkbox show hide div not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, show, show-hide

I am trying to use jQuery show/hide to control the display of a div based on if a checkbox was checked or not. (I had also tried the CSS approach with display none/block.)

I can get the code to either work with checking the checkbox and then having the div show or hide, but, I cannot get my "check all" button to also function in that if the specific checkbox is checked, to show/hide the div accordingly.

I put this into a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gamehendgeVA/2jszhdzw/

Can someone please help me get both the single checkbox checked show/hide working along with the "check all" button showing and hiding the div based on the specific checkbox being checked?

thanks for any help!

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Search These Domains</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="button" value="all domains" id="checkAllDomains" />
<br />
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox" id="domainCheckbox1">One</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Two</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Three</label></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Four</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Five</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Six</label></div>
</div>
</div> <!-- /.panel-body -->
</div> <!-- /.panel -->
<div class="panel panel-info" id="div1">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Search These Divisions</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
THIS DIV SHOULD ONLY APPEAR WHEN "#domainCheckbox1" is checked, either when checked on its own, or checked when the "all domains" button checks it.
</div> <!-- /.panel-body -->
</div> <!-- /.panel -->
```

JS

```
$('#div1').hide();
$('#domainCheckbox1').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $('#div1').show();
  } else {
    $('#div1').hide();
   }
});
/////////
$(function() {
    function updateCheckAllButtonDomains() {
        if ($('.searchDomainCheckbox:checked').length == $('.searchDomainCheckbox').length) {
        $('#checkAllDomains').val('uncheck all').data('check', false);
    } else {
        $('#checkAllDomains').val('all domains').data('check', true);
    }       
}
$('.searchDomainCheckbox').change(function() {
    updateCheckAllButtonDomains();
});
$('#checkAllDomains').click(function() {
    $('.searchDomainCheckbox').prop('checked', $(this).data('check'));
    updateCheckAllButtonDomains();
});
updateCheckAllButtonDomains();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the event of searchDomainCheckbox already been attached to the element. So, you have to trigger manually,like this:`$('.searchDomainCheckbox').trigger('change');`

Put this code on event click of #checkAllDomains and be happy!

This is my solution:

```
$('#checkAllDomains').click(function() {
    $('.searchDomainCheckbox').prop('checked', $(this).data('check'));
    $('.searchDomainCheckbox').trigger('change');
    updateCheckAllButtonDomains();
});
```

Pay Attention: Putting the trigger inside of updateCheckAllButtonDomains()  cause a **"Maximum call stack size exceeded"**.

Comment: Thank you so much... Diptox above was totally on the right track, but I was having some strange problems with not everything consistently showing... Your code (the placement of the trigger change) did the perfect trick, my form looks stable now... thank you so much for helping me... :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2jszhdzw/1/)

Just trigger the Change event and it should work

```
function updateCheckAllButtonDomains() 
{
    if ($('.searchDomainCheckbox:checked').length == $('.searchDomainCheckbox').length)
        $('#checkAllDomains').val('uncheck all').data('check', false);
    else 
        $('#checkAllDomains').val('all domains').data('check', true);

    $("input.searchDomainCheckbox").trigger("change");
}
```

Comment: thank you sooo much, worked like a charm... (little side note that your code up there had the "change" line before the else } , once I moved it after like your Fiddle, works great... thank you so much, I had no idea about that event, will read up on it now :-)

Comment: :D the trigger should be after the if and the else , it will trigger if all are checked or not

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0Lehjbr/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Search These Domains</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAllDomains" />
    <label>Check All</label>
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">One</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Two</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Three</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Four</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Five</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="searchDomainCheckbox">Six</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body -->
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#checkAllDomains').click(function (event) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.searchDomainCheckbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
    } else {
        $('.searchDomainCheckbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```